# number of cases problem(Basic level)

Tags: combinatorics

I've thought about some problem.
for example, it's like this.

there is some people named a,b,c,d,e
and there is their spots called A,B,C,D,E and they are located in their own spot
(a-A,b-B,c-C,d-D,e-E)
and then when they switch each other's spot,
what is the number of cases when nobody is located in their own spot

and I think I found the answer
it's
$$n!-[(n-1)!+(n-3)(n-3)!\times\frac{(n^2-3n+2)}{2}]$$

Does anybody know about this equation?

Comment: It sounds as though you are asking for the number of arrangements where none are located in their original spot.  Such arrangements are called [*derangements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) and are well studied.  Your answer is not correct.  A correct answer and many different ways to arrive at the correct answer are included in the wikipedia link.

Comment: To JMoravitz, thanks for your useful answer! although my question is really trivial, you answered my question, thank you-!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

The simple equation for the number of derangements of $n$ items is $\left[\frac{n!}{e}\right]$, where the square brackets denote the nearest integer, a remarkable and unexpected result.

The recursive formula for derangements $d(n)$ is $d(n) = (n-1)(d(n-1) + d(n-2))$, with $d(0)=1$ and $d(1)=0$. You can infer this from moving the first element to some other location (that's the factor of $n{-}1$) and then either having that value avoid the first spot ($d(n-1)$) or go into the first spot ($d(n-2)$). For $n=0..5$, this gives $d(n)=1,0,1,2,9,44$ - more terms at [OEIS A000166](https://oeis.org/A000166)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! your thoughtful, scrupulous answer moved my mind!, thank you very much, have a good day!